# Was National Geographic just filming a snake attack a child and not helping?

Tags: television, photography, snakes

The picture has become somewhat of a meme (NSFW)

> [image: Picture shows a large snake attacking a child in what appears to be Africa in front of a camera man with "National Geographic" watermark in top right]

Was the boy really being attacked by a snake while the cameramen just taped? Or is this photoshopped or just an act?

Picture reads,

> The "That's Not My Fucking Job" award goes to

Comment: Can you post links of where you've seen this image, rather than just including the image itself?

Comment: Racist and offensive meme websites, I thought it best not to include them since they had no relevant information to the image, just mocking comments

Comment: So what was the cameraman who was taking the picture of the cameraman (i.e. taking this picture) doing?

Comment: Even if this wasn't a dramatization you're assuming the cameraman would be able to aid.  The first rule of rescue is not to become another victim yourself--and that's too much snake for one person to handle.  Finally, there's time to get help, he's not in any immediate, serious danger.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I mean... Those sound like mutually exclusive things - nobody can handle how dangerous the snake is, but it's okay to leave the kid to it, because it's not dangerous? Hmmm.

Comment: @Hellreaver From the way it's wrapped around I expect this is some sort of constrictor snake.  There are rules for how many people based on the length of the snake--I don't recall the exact numbers but a snake that size certainly needs more than one person.  As for the threat level--note where it's wrapped.  Constrictor snakes don't actually crush you to death, they simply keep you from inhaling.  Note that the snake is wrapped around a leg, not the chest.  Assuming it's not staged you get help, you don't deal with it alone.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The image is not from National Geographic, but from the TV show [Nature's Deadliest](https://press.discovery.com/asia-pacific/apl/programs/natures-deadliest/) (image 3 in the slideshow) from Animal Planet.

[image: Original picture used to make the meme, unmodified from Nature's Deadliest promotional materials]

[Waffelsatnoon.com](http://wafflesatnoon.com/boy-attacked-by-snake-as-photographers-watch-real-or-hoax/) and [hoaxorfact.com](http://www.hoaxorfact.com/Miscellaneous/boy-attacked-by-snake-as-photographers-watch-facts.html) both describe it as dramatization (ie acting).

Here is another image from the show, provided by waffelsatnoon.com:

[image]

Comment: For those wondering why they used a child: it's because it's re-enacting a specific incident.

Comment: Note that the WaffelsAtNoon page is not clear that the killing of the cameraman also *was a part of the dramatization act of the program* (according to the HoaxOrFact page).